# How to dsiplay an image in jsp file

Tags: jsp, web-applications

I am trying to display a simple .jpg file in a jsp file. No matter what solutions I have tried I couldnt manage to display the image. Below you see the stripe.jsp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>          
        <form id="form" action="/charge" method="get">   
            <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>  
            <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" />   
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <img src="<c:url value='/drivein12.jpg'/>" />
            <img src="drivein12.jpg" />
            <br></br>
            <b>Price: Euro 2</b>
            <br></br>               
        </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

As you see I am also trying to use the prefix "c" to denote the absolute path of the image (drivein12.jpg). The project structure look like this:

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this? Do I miss something here? Thank you

Comment: Are both of the img tags broken, or just the one that uses <url>?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to view the image in your browser using the url of the image directly (http://yourserver.com/drivein12.jpg)? If you can't do this then you won't be able to embed the image in the page either. Find a direct url for the image that works, and then make sure that the  tag in the page points to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual output of

```
<c:url value='/drivein12.jpg'/>
```

?

You can see this in the source code in the browser, try Ctrl-U when using Firefox.

And by the way: there's no need to close br tags

```
<br></br>
```

Just write

```
<br>
```

or use the XML syntax

```
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your replies.

However I forgot to mention that I m running Spring framework. so the problem was that I needed to tell the framework where to load the images from.

so I added the following line in the -servlet.xml and now it works :

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```